# Is there anyway to tell autohotkey that it has to work only on the desktop, and nowhere else?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I want Autohotkey to be able to distinguish when I am on the desktop, and to run a specific set of shortcuts on the desktop only, and pause those shortcuts when I am not on the Desktop. Is there anyway to do so? I work on a Windows 10 machine.

I have attached a simple drawing if my language is not very clear.

[image]

Comment: Open Window Spy that comes with the AHK installation and switch to your desktop. For me on Windows 10, it shows `ahk_class Progman`.

Comment: See https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm.

Comment: **THANK YOU!** Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ideas:
A loop that checks the active window.
A context-sensitive hotkey that works only when Desktop is active.

```
Loop
{
WinGetClass, vWinClass, A

if vWinClass in Progman,WorkerW
{
;do this
}
else
{
;do that
}

Sleep 5000
}

;==================================================

GroupAdd, vGroupDesktop, ahk_class Progman ;desktop
GroupAdd, vGroupDesktop, ahk_class WorkerW ;desktop

#IfWinActive, ahk_group vGroupDesktop
^q::
;do this
Return
#IfWinActive
```

Note:
Two separate scripts running at the same time might be an idea to consider.